# Are there  (semi) standard font symbols for SAVE, RUN, etc in TeX?

Tags: fonts, symbols

Is there a font package to represent typical computer commands such as Save, Run, Refresh, etc? I am looking for something in the spirit of  [KeyStroke](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/keystroke) package for typical command icons on screen.

Comment: Can you point to some on-line resource for them?

Comment: Usual symbol for SAVE is a floppy disk, and for RUN many are used, but one I have seen often is a green circle with a triangle pointing right (similar to what `TeXWorks` uses).

Comment: @egreg for Refresh the usual symbol is a circular arrow, as in say Chrome, for Save TeXWork uses a curved arrow pointing to a disk, others use just a disk (as Peter Grill said). I am looking for the name of the font package, if there is one.

Comment: To partially answer my own question there is  http://tex.blogoverflow.com/?blt=1  where sprite sheets are introduced making it possible to incorporate certain icons if you can find your favorite image on one of those sheets.

Comment: This looks off-topic for us as it's really not TeX related. It might fit on graphicdesign-sx, but even there I am not sure in the current form.

Comment: @JosephWright: I disagree. This is not off-topic at all. Maesumi wants to perhaps typeset these symbols in his document and he does not know how. Well, we can not classify everything as off-topic if we do not have a solution for it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't a standard collection of symbols for this specific purpose. `:(` And [the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://texdoc.net/show.php?pkg=symbols) doesn't have anything like this.

Those icons are used in the cognitive approach for HCI design. It's also known as metaphoric design, because we use metaphors to express abstract concepts or procedures. For example, as Peter mentioned it, using a `floppy disk` to express the `save` action is something familiar to user. Using such symbols might help users to quickly learn the basics of a new system.

In the sprite sheet blog post, I mentioned the [Tango Icon Library](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Icon_Library) (thanks to Joseph who pointed it in the chatroom). They have [some suggestions](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Tango_icons) for icons on metaphoric design:

[image: Tango suggestions]

<sup>*To name a few, there's a ton more. `:)`*</sup>

Since you want to include these icons in a TeX document, I'd recommend you to stick with vector formats. `:)` Tango has `.svg` formats available, so we could convert them to `.pdf` files.

As an example, I selected six of those icons and added them to [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/):

[image: Inkscape]

The colored boxes were added only for visual reference. `:)` Every icon is placed inside a `48px x 48px` box. The next step is to export the document to `.pdf` from Inkscape, which is very straightforward.

Now, let's go to the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\copyicon}{%
\adjustimage{dpi=90,Clip={0px 0px 240px 0px},height=1.8ex,width=1.8ex}{myicons}\xspace}
\newcommand{\cuticon}{%
\adjustimage{dpi=90,Clip={48px 0px 192px 0px},height=1.8ex,width=1.8ex}{myicons}\xspace}
\newcommand{\previewicon}{%
\adjustimage{dpi=90,Clip={96px 0px 144px 0px},height=1.8ex,width=1.8ex}{myicons}\xspace}
\newcommand{\pasteicon}{%
\adjustimage{dpi=90,Clip={144px 0px 96px 0px},height=1.8ex,width=1.8ex}{myicons}\xspace}
\newcommand{\redoicon}{%
\adjustimage{dpi=90,Clip={192px 0px 48px 0px},height=1.8ex,width=1.8ex}{myicons}\xspace}
\newcommand{\undoicon}{%
\adjustimage{dpi=90,Clip={240px 0px 0px 0px},height=1.8ex,width=1.8ex}{myicons}\xspace}

\begin{document}

To copy a text selection, move your mouse cursor to the text
you want to copy and highlight it. Then press \copyicon to copy
it to the clipboard. To retrieve the selection, simply click the
\pasteicon icon and the text will be pasted in the current document.

\vspace{1em}

\Large Beware of the \cuticon icon, it will cut the current text!

\vspace{1em}

\Huge Don't worry, \redoicon can revert it.

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Icons]

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: Hahaha, evil `undo` symbol. Why not adding *`Alt+F4` will save your document...*

Comment: @percusse: LOL it's a good idea. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda  Thanks, that looks great. By the way I have heard of a picture language for the deaf, but have not seen it. Do you know of any such picture library?

Comment: @Maesumi: I'm sorry, but I really don't know about such library. I've seen a few images of hand gestures to indicate numbers or letters of the alphabet, but nothing more. `:(`